# how to solve: UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_write Value: 7,failed to write file to disk

Tags: php, linux, file-upload

I have a php uploader as below

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="jsonlog.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

In the jsonlog.php:

```
if($_FILES['file']['error']>0)
{
    echo "Reading Error: " . $_FILES['file']["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
  code to process
}
```

It passed on my localhost, but when I tried on a linux server, it always gave me error:

UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_write Value: 7,failed to write file to disk. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks

---

Yes, I checked the tmp directory permission, see below

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 bitnami bitnami  4096 2011-09-21 13:34 tmp
```

I can created a new file in the tmp using command like

```
sudo vi test.txt
```

the uploader still returns the error PLOAD_ERR_CANT_write.

There is one more thing that I don't understand: I log in as bitnami, I should have full control to the folder tmp, but I cannot write files into tmp using command without sudo

```
vi t.txt
```

I cannot save the changes. It returns this error

```
E514: write error (file system full?)
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!
```

Here is the output of df command

```
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.9G  9.4G     0 100% /
devtmpfs              854M  116K  854M   1% /dev
none                  871M     0  871M   0% /dev/shm
none                  871M   48K  871M   1% /var/run
none                  871M     0  871M   0% /var/lock
none                  871M     0  871M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda2             335G  195M  318G   1% /mnt
```

but when I run sudo du -sh, the output is

```
/$ sudo du -sh /
du: cannot access `/proc/32760/task/32760/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/32760/task/32760/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/32760/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/32760/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
855M    /
```

It is far from full. Anybody can tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if the directory is writeable / have you checked all permissions? The error says you can't write the file, due to permissions problems..

Comment: Running out of disk space is another reason. If /tmp is size-constrained, an upload could very well fill it up.

Comment: yes, this problem is due to running out of disk space. Thanks